# CDI bean is not injected but can be looked up

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, cdi, inject

So, I wrote an extension which registers bean I am trying to create. The bean gets scanned by CDI and I can get it using:

```
MyInterface myInterface = CDI.current().select(MyInterface.class).get();
```

And I can then access `myInterface.myMethod();`

However, when I try to inject my bean using:

```
@Inject
@MyBean
MyInterface myInterface;
```

it is **not injected and is null**.

What I want to achieve is that I specify interface, which defines some methods,then my code generates instance of this interface and returns proxy of interface type:

```
// defined interface
@RegisterAsMyBean
interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod();
}

// usage in code:
@Inject
@MyBean
MyInterface myInterface;
```

I declared my bean like this:

```
public class MyExtension implements Extension {
    public void register(@Observes @WithAnnotations(RegisterAsMyBean.class) ProcessAnnotatedType<?> aType) {
        Class<?> typeDef = aType.getAnnotatedType().getJavaClass();

        if(typeDef.isInterface()) {
            proxyTypes.add(typeDef);
            aType.veto();
        }
    }
}

public class BeanCreator implements Bean<Object> {
    @Override
    public Object create(CreationalContext<Object> creationalContext) {
        // my instance building logic
    }
    // ... other overriden methods
}
```

Also in META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension I put reference to MyExtension

Comment: `@MyBean` is a qualifier i guess. During the creation of the `Bean` does it specify `@MyBean` as one of the set of qualifiers? In any case... CDI should have complained with `NoBeanDefinitionException`

Comment: i haven't been setting any of the qualifiers, no (still learning about cdi), however the CDI does not complain, but rather method with lookup works as i intended. that is what i find strange

Comment: Few questions - what is `@MyBean`? Where did you try to select your bean using `CDI.current()` and there are you trying to `@Inject` it? It may be that you are trying to inject it into non-contextual instance or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in bean creation lifecycle - i was trying to create bean in processAnnotatedType cycle, while I should have done that during afterBeanDiscovery cycle.

After moving my bean creation logic to appropriate cycle the bean is created and properly injected.